# Place holder error in values section of the SQL query

Tags: python, pyodbc

Hi I am trying to import data into an access database from excel using python.

Below is my code that i tried

```
import xlrd
import pyodbc
# opening the excel sheets
incoming=xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Incoming.xlsx')
sheet_incoming=incoming.sheet_by_name('Incoming')
print(sheet_incoming)

# connecting to access database
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Desktop\E CX DB.accdb;')
dbcurs=conn.cursor()



incoming_query = """INSERT INTO Incoming (SR_NO,SUP,ID,TYPE,SETUP_DATE,BU,Month_,Year_,RAF_IND)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
for r in range(1,sheet_incoming.nrows):
    SR_NO = sheet_incoming.cell(r,0).value
    SUP = sheet_incoming.cell(r,1).value
    ID = sheet_incoming.cell(r,2).value
    TYPE = sheet_incoming.cell(r,3).value
    SETUP_DATE = sheet_incoming.cell(r,4).value
    BU = sheet_incoming.cell(r,5).value
    Month_ = sheet_incoming.cell(r,6).value
    Year_ = sheet_incoming.cell(r,7).value
    RAF_IND = sheet_incoming.cell(r,8).value

    #assigning values
    values =(SR_NO,SUP,ID,TYPE,SETUP_DATE,BU,Month_,Year_,RAF_IND)

    # execute upload
    dbcurs.execute(incoming_query,values)
dbcurs.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Error that i get is `Syntax error in query expression '%s'. (-3100) (SQLPrepare)")`

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Your error message is pretty clear. Your SQL says you're only inserting one value, but you're providing 6. Either your query needs to be adjusted, or you need to ensure that you're only inserting the first column of the Excel data.

Comment: fixed it by using `?` instead of %s